# How to properly pass input values to a function using the composition api in vue?

Tags: vue-composition-api

I have an input field that contains a postcode. On submit I want to pass the postcode as an object to an axios request. I have created a CodeSandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-beaver-8ebqc

The relevant code is:

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input v-model="postcode" type="text" placeholder="Enter Postcode">
    <button @click="getAddress">Submit</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import useAxios from "@/composition/use-axios";

  export default {
  name: "App",
  setup() {
    const { sentData, response, fetchData } = useAxios(
      "api/address/lookup-address",
      "postcode",
      "Failed Finding Address"
    );
    return {
      postcode: sentData,
      address: response,
      getAddress: fetchData
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

use-axios.js

```
import { reactive, toRefs } from "@vue/composition-api";
import axios from "axios";

export default function (url, objectData, errorMessage) {
  const state = reactive({
    sentData: null,
    response: null
  });
  const fetchData = async () => {
    console.log("Sent Data:", state.sentData);
    console.log("Response:", state.response);
    console.log("URL:", url);
    console.log("Object Data:", objectData);
    console.log("Object:", { [objectData]: state.sentData });
    console.log("Error Message:", errorMessage);
    const config = { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } };
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(url, [objectData]: state.sentData, config);
      state.response = await res.data;
    } catch (error) {
      // Error handling stuff
    }
  }

  return { ...toRefs(state), fetchData };
}
```

Converting the postcode input string to an object in this way seems very hacky. Also, this would get very messy if I needed to send multiple parameters to the axios request. Say if I want to pass `{ id: "1234", user: "Me" }`, I would like to be able to construct that like:

`sentData = { id: ${id}, user: ${user} }`

But I'm not able to do this. What is the proper way to do this so that I can keep use-axios generic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to import ref, reactive and computed from the composition-api and then use them like this:

```
<script>
import useAxios from "@/composition/use-axios";
import { ref, reactive, computed } from "@vue/composition-api";

export default {
  name: "App",

  setup() {
    let object = ref("");
    let state = reactive({ postcode: "" });
    const sentDataObject = computed(() => {
      state.postcode = object;
      return state;
    });
    const addressList = useAxios(
      "api/address/lookup-address",
      sentDataObject.value,
      "Failed Finding Address"
    );

    return {
      addresses: addressList.response,
      postcode: object,
      getAddress: addressList.fetchData
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

change use-axios.js to:

```
import { reactive, toRefs } from "@vue/composition-api";
import axios from "axios";

export default function (url, objectData, errorMessage) {
  const state = reactive({
    sentData: null,
    response: null
  });
  const fetchData = async () => {
    console.log("Sent Data:", state.sentData);
    console.log("Response:", state.response);
    console.log("URL:", url);
    console.log("Object Data:", objectData);
    console.log("Error Message:", errorMessage);
    const config = { headers: { "Content-Type": 
"application/json" } };
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(url, objectData, config);
      state.response = await res.data;
    } catch (error) {
      // Error handling stuff
    }
  };
  return { ...toRefs(state), fetchData };
}
```

See Codesandbox demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-glade-ewzb7